# Bootstrap Form Input Float Value Issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have used bootstrap 4 framework in my website. Using this framework I have created a simple html form using bootstrap class with javascript function.

The form works good while i enter integer as input, But it shows some error while i enter float vales.

Here is the [web-page](https://www.azcalculator.com/calc/avogadro-number.php).

```
<form role="form" name="BeamFactor">    
    <div class="form-group">            
        <label>Antenna dimension (D) :</label>
        <input class="form-control input-lg" name="n1" required="" type="number"> 
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">        
        <label>Wavelength (λ) :</label><input class="form-control input-lg" name="n2" type="number"> 
    </div>      

    <div class="form-group">        
        <label>Beamwidth :</label><input class="form-control input-lg" name="n3" type="number"> 
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">            
        <input value="Calculate" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="javascript:calcBeamFactor();" type="button">   
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Reset</button> 
    </div>      

    <div class="form-group">        
        <label>BF :</label><input class="form-control input-lg" name="total"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add step property to your input type.

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```